# Maximum number of non-congruent triangles with side lengths integers and less than $9$

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the maximum number of non-congruent triangles whose side lengths are integers and less than $9$.

I tried using brute force to count all the triangles but there are so many triangles that can be formed and I counted about $60$ of them but after that I gave up. Is there any systematic approach to question?

Answer (score 3):

We do some systematic counting.

First the isosceles (including equilateral) ones. If the base is $1$, other two sides can be any from $1$ to $8$. If base is $2$, other two can be any from $2$ to $8$. If base is $3$ - $2$ to $8$. Base $4$ - $3$ to $8$. Base $5$ - $3$ to $8$. Base $6$ - $4$ to $8$. Base $7$ - $4$ to $8$. Base $8$ - $5$ to $8$. Total $$8+7+7+6+6+5+5+4=48$$

For scalene, we write the triplet of side lengths in decreasing order respecting triangle inequality.

- $[8,7,(6 \,\text{to}\, 2)]. [8,6,(5\,\text{to}\, 3)]. [8, 5, 4]. [8,4,✗].$
- $[7,6,(5 \,\text{to}\, 2)]. [7,5,(4 \,\text{to}\, 3)]. [7, 4, ✗].$
- $[6,5,(4 \,\text{to}\, 2)]. [6,4,3]. [6, 3, ✗].$
- $[5,4,(3 \,\text{to}\, 2)]. [5,3,✗].$
- $[4,3,2]. [4,2,✗].$
- $[3,2,✗].$

Sum : $5+3+1+4+2+3+1+2+1=22$

Grand total : $\boxed{48+22=70}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a systematic approach is to count the number of triples of three integers which satisfy the triangle inequality. All that this requires is that the two shorter lengths must add up to more than the greatest length.

**Longest side 8**

The other sides can then be 8 and 8,8 and 7,...,8 and 1 OR 7 and 7, 7 and 6,...,7+2 OR etc.

The total number is $8+6+4+2=20$.

**Longest side 7**

The total number is $7+5+3+1=16$

**Longest side 6,5, ...**

The totals for these are $12,9,6,4,2,1$.

**Grand total**

We must now add these  numbers, obtaining $70$.

**A generalisation**

Note the numbers we added above are the squares plus twice the triangular numbers:-
$$1+4+9+16+2(1+3+6+10).$$

We can generalises this result to other bounds on the side lengths.

Comment: Don't forget the triangle inequality; $a+b > c$ for the side lengths. Take $c$ as longest side (other cases trivially true).

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I said in the opening paragraph! Unfortunately I then added in lots of invalid ones.

Comment: Ok that looks a lot better :-)

Comment: Thanks. I quite like the fact that (done correctly) there's the nice generalisation noted above.

Comment: The chart in Somos' answer illustrates nicely why this works too, alternately adding a square (eg. the row for 7) and a double triangular (eg. 8)

Comment: If the side length were given less than 10 then we would have taken summation of square of  first 5 numbers and then twice of summation of first 4 triangular

Comment: And id side length were less than 11 then both would have been 5 and 5 . Am i right

Comment: Yes - that's it.

Comment: Is there a way this could to be extended to a question which gives a set random integers and asks us to count no of triangles

Comment: Looking at expected number of triangles presumably? There certainly are results on breaking sticks into 3 parts and determining whether or not they can form a  triangle.

Comment: Is there a sequence like this for quadrilateral

Comment: The triangle inequality part is OK since you just require the sum of the three smaller lengths to  be greater than the length of the longest side. However, knowing  4 sides does not fix the shape of a quadrilateral so you have to dispense with the congruence idea and just say 'triangles with different side lengths'.

Comment: I just read on google that for quadrilateral sum of 3 sides should be greater than 4th side

Comment: Yes, that's "you just require the sum of the three smaller lengths to be greater than the length of the longest side". The same idea is true for all polygons and is equivalent to the 'shortest distance between two points idea'.

Answer (score 2):

The number of non congruent non degenerate triangles
with integer sides with largest side equal to $\,n+1\,$
is the [OEIS sequence A002623](https://oeis.org/A002623).
For $\,n=7\,$ the answer is $70.$ The OEIS entry has a
comment which justifies the interpretation as count of
triangles

> Also number of triples (x,y,z) with 0 < x <= y <= z <= n + 1, x + y > z. - Ralf Steiner, Feb 06 2020

The formula

> A002620(n+3) = a(n+1) - a(n). - Michael Somos, Sep 04 1999

means that the first differences of the triangle counts
is the quarter-squares sequence [A002620](https://oeis.org/A002620).

Alternatively, the
[OEIS sequence A173196](https://oeis.org/A173196)
has two extra zeros at the beginning of the sequence.
Thus it is the number of non congruent non degenerate
triangles with integer sides with largest side $\,<n.\,$
The value for $\,n=9\,$ is again $70$. The
triangle counts arranged as a number triangle
[OEIS sequence A003983](https://oeis.org/A003983)
with $\,n\,$ the largest side and $\,m\,$ the
smallest side makes the pattern clear.

```
 n\m 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10   row sum accum sum
 -+------------------------------   ------- ---------
 1|  1                                  1        1
 2|  1  1                               2        3          
 3|  1  2  1                            4        7
 4|  1  2  2  1                         6       13
 5|  1  2  3  2  1                      9       22
 6|  1  2  3  3  2  1                  12       34
 7|  1  2  3  4  3  2  1               16       50
 8|  1  2  3  4  4  3  2  1            20       70
 9|  1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1         25       95
10|  1  2  3  4  5  5  4  3  2  1      30      125
```

Comment: I guess i understood the pattern ...If the side length was given less than 10 so the no of triangles will 85... Am i right

Comment: Oh sry it would have 95 ,right?

Comment: Really like the tabular presentation here, it answers a lot of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Put $L$ to be the longest side, an $x,y$ the other two.

> We can limit ourselves in considering $x \le y$.

Then we shall have
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x \le y \le L \hfill \cr 
  L \le x + y \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which is the area within the triangle $VCB$
in this sketch
[image: Triang_Int_1]
and which is equivalent to triangle $OVA$, which
in turn is half of the triangle $OAC$.

Now, the number of integer points inside the right triangle $OAC$ with sides $[0,L]$, **including the borders i.e. the equalities**
is
$$
N_{\,OAC}  = 1 + 2 +  \cdots  + \left( {L + 1} \right)
 = \left( \matrix{  L + 2 \cr   2 \cr}  \right)
$$
while those on the segment $OV$ are
$$
N_{\,OV}  = \left\lfloor {L/2} \right\rfloor  + 1
$$

So the number we are looking for is
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & N = \left( {{{N_{\,OAC}  - N_{\,OV} } \over 2}} \right) + N_{\,OV}
  = {1 \over 2}\left( {N_{\,OAC}  + N_{\,OV} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\left( {\left( \matrix{  L + 2 \cr   2 \cr}  \right)
 + \left\lfloor {L/2} \right\rfloor  + 1} \right) \cr} 
}$$

which for $L= 1, \ldots,10$ gives
$$
2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 16, 20, 25, 30, 36
$$

If instead you are not going to consider the degenerated cases $x=0, \; x+y=L$ then it is easy
to deduct from the above the corresponding side lengths.